# How to translate data.table code to collapse

Tags: r, data.table, r-collapse

I read about the [collapse](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/index.html) package recently and tried to translate the following `data.table` code to `collapse` to see if it's faster in real world examples.

Here's my `data.table` code:

```r
library(data.table)
library(nycflights13)

data("flights")
flights_DT <- as.data.table(flights)

val_var <- "arr_delay"
id_var <- "carrier"
by <- c("month", "day")

flights_DT[
  j = list(agg_val_var = sum(abs(get(val_var)), na.rm = TRUE)), 
  keyby = c(id_var, by)
][
  i = order(-agg_val_var), 
  j = list(value_share = cumsum(agg_val_var)/sum(agg_val_var)), 
  keyby = by
][
  j = .SD[2L],
  keyby = by
][
  order(-value_share)
]
#>      month day value_share
#>   1:    10   3   0.5263012
#>   2:     1  24   0.5045664
#>   3:     1  20   0.4885145
#>   4:    10  17   0.4870692
#>   5:     3   6   0.4867606
#>  ---                      
#> 361:     5   4   0.3220295
#> 362:     6  15   0.3205974
#> 363:     1  28   0.3197260
#> 364:    11  25   0.3161550
#> 365:     6  14   0.3128286
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I managed to translate the first `data.table` call, but struggled later on.

It would be great to see how `collapse` would be used to handle this use case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it only makes sense to translate `data.table` code to `collapse` if

1. you've come up with an arcane expression in `data.table` to do something complex statistical it is is not good at (such as weighted aggregation, computing quantiles or the mode by groups, lagging / differencing an irregular panel, grouped centering or linear / polynomial fitting)
2. you actually don't need the `data.table` object but would much rather work with vectors / matrices / data.frame's / tibbles
3. you want to write a statistical program and would much prefer standard evaluation programming over NS eval and `data.table` syntax or
4. `collapse` is indeed substantially faster for your specific application.

Now to the specific code you have provided. It mixes standard and non-standard evaluation (e.g. through the use of `get()`), which is something `collapse` is not very good at. I'll give you 3 solutions ranging from full NS eval to full standard eval base R style programming.

```r
library(data.table)
library(nycflights13)
library(magrittr)
library(collapse)

data("flights")
flights_DT <- as.data.table(flights)

# Defining a function for the second aggregation
myFUN <- function(x) (cumsum(x[1:2])/sum(x))[2L]

# Soluting 1: Non-Standard evaluation
flights_DT %>%
  fgroup_by(carrier, month, day) %>% 
  fsummarise(agg_val_var = fsum(abs(arr_delay))) %>% 
  roworder(month, day, -agg_val_var, na.last = NA) %>%
  fgroup_by(month, day) %>%
  fsummarise(value_share = myFUN(agg_val_var)) %>% 
  roworder(-value_share)
#>      month day value_share
#>   1:    10   3   0.5263012
#>   2:     1  24   0.5045664
#>   3:     1  20   0.4885145
#>   4:    10  17   0.4870692
#>   5:     3   6   0.4867606
#>  ---                      
#> 361:     5   4   0.3220295
#> 362:     6  15   0.3205974
#> 363:     1  28   0.3197260
#> 364:    11  25   0.3161550
#> 365:     6  14   0.3128286
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note the use of `na.last = NA` wich actually removes cases where `agg_val_var` is missing. This is needed here because `fsum(NA)` is `NA` and not `0` like `sum(NA, na.rm = TRUE)`. Now the hybrid example which is probably closes to the code you provided:

```r
val_var <- "arr_delay"
id_var <- "carrier"
by <- c("month", "day")

# Solution 2: Hybrid approach with standard eval and magrittr pipes
flights_DT %>%
  get_vars(c(id_var, val_var, by)) %>%
  ftransformv(val_var, abs) %>% 
  collapv(c(id_var, by), fsum) %>%
  get_vars(c(by, val_var)) %>%
  roworderv(decreasing = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), na.last = NA) %>%
  collapv(by, myFUN) %>%
  roworderv(val_var, decreasing = TRUE) %>%
  frename(replace, names(.) == val_var, "value_share")
#>      month day value_share
#>   1:    10   3   0.5263012
#>   2:     1  24   0.5045664
#>   3:     1  20   0.4885145
#>   4:    10  17   0.4870692
#>   5:     3   6   0.4867606
#>  ---                      
#> 361:     5   4   0.3220295
#> 362:     6  15   0.3205974
#> 363:     1  28   0.3197260
#> 364:    11  25   0.3161550
#> 365:     6  14   0.3128286
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note here that I used `frename` at the end to give the result column the name you wanted, as you cannot mix standard and non-standard eval in the same function in `collapse`. Finally, a big advantage of `collapse` is that you can use it for pretty low-level programming:

```r
# Solution 3: Programming
data <- get_vars(flights_DT, c(id_var, val_var, by))
data[[val_var]] <- abs(.subset2(data, val_var))
g <- GRP(data, c(id_var, by))
data <- add_vars(get_vars(g$groups, by), 
                 fsum(get_vars(data, val_var), g, use.g.names = FALSE))
data <- roworderv(data, decreasing = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), na.last = NA)
g <- GRP(data, by)
columns
data <- add_vars(g$groups, list(value_share = BY(.subset2(data, val_var), g, myFUN, use.g.names = FALSE)))
data <- roworderv(data, "value_share", decreasing = TRUE)
data
#>      month day value_share
#>   1:    10   3   0.5263012
#>   2:     1  24   0.5045664
#>   3:     1  20   0.4885145
#>   4:    10  17   0.4870692
#>   5:     3   6   0.4867606
#>  ---                      
#> 361:     5   4   0.3220295
#> 362:     6  15   0.3205974
#> 363:     1  28   0.3197260
#> 364:    11  25   0.3161550
#> 365:     6  14   0.3128286
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I refer you to the blog post on [programming](https://sebkrantz.github.io/Rblog/2020/09/13/programming-with-collapse/) with `collapse` for a more interesting example on how this can benefit the development of statistical codes.

Now for the evaluation, I wrapped these solutions in functions, where `DT()` is the `data.table` code you provided, run with 2 threads on a windows machine. This checks equality:

```r
all_obj_equal(DT(), clp_NSE(), clp_Hybrid(), clp_Prog())
#> TRUE
```

Now the benchmark:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(DT(), clp_NSE(), clp_Hybrid(), clp_Prog())
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#>          DT() 85.81079 87.80887 91.82032 89.47025 92.54601 132.26073   100   b
#>     clp_NSE() 13.47535 14.15744 15.99264 14.80606 16.29140  28.16895   100  a 
#>  clp_Hybrid() 13.79843 14.23508 16.61606 15.00196 16.83604  32.94648   100  a 
#>    clp_Prog() 13.71320 14.17283 16.16281 14.94395 16.16935  39.24706   100  a
```

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer, especially for the explanatory remarks at the beginning. Based on this, I don't think `collapse` is a natural fit for my use case. But I'll keep it in mind and hopefully will give it a try later.